# How to setup vue.js to ignore anchor tags?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-router

I use **VueRouter** with **HTML5 history mode**. And I use bootstrap 'Navs' with anchor tags. Vue application is reloaded when user clicks on any anchor tag.

example of html

```
<a href="#tab_contacts" data-toggle="tab">Contacts</a>
```

Is any approach to ignore anchor tags by router?

Comment: Router already ignores the anchor tags. The problem might exist somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [canDeactivate hook](http://router.vuejs.org/en/pipeline/can-deactivate.html) to stop vue from reload page,for example:

```
  route: {
    //called before page deactivate
    canDeactivate: function(transition) {
        if(...){//check if the route should be ignored

           transition.abort(); //this will stop vue-router from reloading the page
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kaicui, you solution doesn't work for anchor tags. It works only for vue links.